# Filtrar los resultados de consulta a API en Phyton

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Phyton en el cual debo consumir una API y hacer 2 cosas:
1-Mostrar todos los registros segun el parametro que se le pase (en este caso Notebooks)
2- Filtrar los resultados obtenidos segun el Retail_Label que el usuario requiera

Hasta el momento creo que obtengo los datos de la api:

```
filtro = 'notebook'
api_url = f'https://knasta.cl/api/results?q={filtro}'

notebooks = requests.get(api_url).json()['products']

for notebook in notebooks:
    print(notebook['title'])
```

Lo que me da como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no entiendo como debo hacer la consigna del filtro (sobre lo que ya obtengo), por ejemplo filtrar por Retail_Label = 'Lider'

El JSON en bruto que obtengo es asi:

```
{'q': 'notebook',
 'order': 'relevance',
 'k': 0,
 'count': 1597,
 'total_pages': 50,
 'page': 1,
 'page_size': 32,
 'products': [{'images': 'https://i.linio.com/p/b739956b87da2705dbea61837b633c27-product.jpg',
   'kid': 'linio#HP034EL14QS94LACL',
   'title': 'Notebook Envy X360  8Gb Ram 512Gb Ssd 13.3\\ - Hp',
   'percent': -17,
   'retail': 'linio',
   'prev_price': '$ 849.990',
   'days_old': 89,
   'price': '$ 699.990',
   'price_tm': 849990.0,
   'product_id': 'HP034EL14QS94LACL',
   'kategory': '2000',
   'price_value': 699990.0,
   'ktype': 11,
   'retail_label': 'Linio'},
  {'images': 'https://images.lider.cl/wmtcl?source=url[file:/productos/1138885a.jpg]&sink',
   'kid': 'lider#1138885',
   'title': 'Dell - Notebook Inspiron Gaming 15 3501 /I3-1005G1 /4Gb /1Tb/ 15Inch/ Win10',
   'percent': -14,
   'retail': 'lider',
   'prev_price': '$ 469.990',
   'days_old': 60,
   'price': '$ 399.990',
   'price_tm': 409990.0,
   'product_id': '1138885',
   'kategory': '1000',
   'price_value': 399990.0,
   'ktype': 3,
   'retail_label': 'Lider Electrohogar'},
```

Entonces con este codigo puedo imprimir un DataFrame Sin Filtro:

```
result = requests.get(api_url).json()['products']

#Creamos el DataFrame Sin Filtro
df_totals = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Ahora necesito crear un DataFrame Independiente que lleve el filtro, dicho filtro lo estoy creando asi:

```
retail = df[df["retail"]=='linio']
```

Pero de esta manera solo consigo mostrar el DF filtrado si lo invoco asi: retail, intente renombrando asi:

```
df_filtrado = retail = df[df["retail"]=='linio']
```

pero no me funciona

Saludos a todos, atento a sus comentarios

Comment: Si utilizas pandas todo se vuelve más fácil

Comment: entiendo que con Pandas renderizo en el DataFrame los resultados, pero no se si se peude filtrar el json antes de renderizarlo

Comment: puedes hacerlo de cualquier forma, sería bueno que pongas el json y así podré darte una respuesta

Comment: @Christian gracias, añadi una parte del json que obtengo al consultar la api

Comment: El primer error que te deberia salir es `df is not defined` pues tu creas tu dataframe con el nombre de `df_totals` y con ese nombre tendrás que hacer el filtro

Comment: Luego no hace falta renombrar ni ganas variable ni nada, con un `print(df_totals)` y un `print(retail)` bastará para mostrar el dataframe en bruto y el filtrado

Comment: si de eso me di cuenta, solo que en el ejercicio me pedian que fueran 2 dataframes (df_retail que seria el filtrado y df_totals que es el no filtrado)

Comment: Eso es lo que te digo :/. Como última sugerencia pon las etiquetas correspondientes, voy a editar tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo conseguí, tengo la Data en bruto y Filtrada en DataFrame separados:

```
#Asignamos todo el resultado de la consulta a una variable manejable
result = requests.get(api_url).json()['products']

#Creamos el DataFrame Sin Filtro
df_totals = pd.DataFrame(result)

#Creamos DataFrame Segun Retail
df_retail = retail = df_retail[df_retail["retail"]=='lider']
```

De esa manera ya puedo invocar al que se necesite...

Comment: No hace falta hacer una doble asignación de variable, con solo usar la primera basta, además veo un poco de incongruencias en tu código. Estas usando jupyter notebook?